# Perl sleep terminated by SIGCHLD

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;

sub REAPER {
  my $pid;
  while (($pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
      print "where is here,$pid\n";
  }
}

sub child {
  print "I'm child, pid=$$.\n";
  sleep 2;
}

$lid = fork();
if ($lid == 0) {
    &child;
    exit;
} else {
    sleep 1000;
    print "I am parent, child pid : $lid\n";
}
```

Output:

```
I'm child, pid=11839.
where is here,11839
I am parent, child pid : 11839
```

The above is my Perl script. The output is right, but one strange thing is that it prints `I am parent, child pid : 11839` immediately after the last output. Why didn't the `sleep 1000` have any effect?

Answer (score 8):

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html): "May be interrupted if the process receives a signal". The whole point is to allow signal handlers to run. Just go back to sleep if it's not time to wake up.

```
use Time::HiRes qw( time sleep );  # Optional.

sub unint_sleep($) {
    my $sleep_til = time + $_[0];
    while (1) {
        my $sleep_dur = $sleep_til - time;
        last if $sleep_dur <= 0;
        sleep($sleep_dur);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but there's a problem there: `time - $sleep_til` is always negative, and the function is not sleeping at all. It should be `$sleep_til-time`

Answer (score 2):

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare your symbols using `my` at their point of definition. This applies especially when you are asking for help, as these measures can reveal simple bugs that are otherwise easily overlooked

`sleep` is implemented by using `setitimer` to request a `SIGALRM` after a specified interval, and then `pause` to suspend the process until it gets the signal.

But if a `SIGCHLD` comes first this will also wake the process.

The signal mask cannot be set to prevent this as otherwise the `SIGCHLD` wouldn't get serviced

Comment: That is not how `sleep` is implemented, in most OSes/Perls from this decade, or in the kernel. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

Comment: @ZacB: I'm looking at the C source of Perl v5.24 and your comment seems unfair. Please add an answer that defines properly how a Perl `sleep` call works in your eyes. Note that it doesn't call `usleep` that you linked to.

Comment: @ZacB  So how is it implemented?  I would like to know, if it isn't this way. The link you provide is just the man page for `usleep` what doesn't tell me anything about how Perl implements its own. Perl's page for [sleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) in fact hints at `setitimer`. Note that `usleep` _from a module_ that is mentioned seems _not to_ use that syscall (see module's docs). Can you provide some docs or pointers?

Comment: See `strace perl -e 'sleep(10);'`. No calls to `alarm` or `setitimer` are made on platforms I have used, and no signals are delivered; instead, calls are made to `nanosleep`and friends. Also, since there's only one `alarm`/`setitimer` clock per process (in Unix, at least), implementing `sleep` with alarms would clobber user-set alarms, which does not happen; see `time perl -e 'alarm(2); sleep(10);'`.